# Android - com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLiteException: getViewId() < 0

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I am new to couchbase lite.

**What I have done till now:**

1. create documents on my couchbase cloud and created views (all views returning rows as expected)
2. Established connection and pulled documents from cloud to android device
3. Correctly retrieve and view all documents on my android device

**My problem is:**

When I do:

```
Query query = database.getView("getCategory").createQuery();
//query.setStartKey("m");
query.setLimit(100);
QueryEnumerator result;

try {
    result = query.run();


} catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the error:

```
com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLiteException: getViewId() < 0
at com.couchbase.lite.View.updateIndex(View.java:376)
at com.couchbase.lite.Database.queryViewNamed(Database.java:2046)
at com.couchbase.lite.Query.run(Query.java:350)
at com.example.helloworldeclipse.MainActivity.retrieveByView(MainActivity.java:133)
at com.example.helloworldeclipse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I understand that the call of the method database.getView(view name) is not returning any view.

My document-view is as follows:

```
    retrievedDocument={_rev=2-01da195a3162c4bfd3c42996e8c13ea8, language=javascript, _id=_design/getCategory, views={getCategory={map=function(doc) {
if (doc.idCategoryParent && doc.class == "category" ) {
emit(doc.idCategoryParent, doc.categoryName);
  }
 }}}}
```

I have tried calling it like getView("_design/getCategory/getCategory") as "_design/getCategory" the document name and "getCategory" as the view name... but still resulting in the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that you need specify if is descending and the limit as a normal view query in couch db. Try adding: `query.setDescending(true);
query.setLimit(20);` just before your `query.run()` and verify if the name of your view is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't solve it

Comment: Beekarre this is the complete log error?

Comment: Yes, this is all logs received from couchbase lite android

Comment: Beekaree and it's working using your console? (to check your connectivity)

Comment: Did you set the map function somehere in your view?